# Remove Extra scroll with react-navigation/bottom-tabs

Tags: react-native, bottomnavigationview, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I made a very simple test application with React Native and react-navigation/bottom-tabs but there is a small extra scroll that appears when adding this bottom tab. See picture below. Is there any way to remove it ?

[image]

The code is the following:

**App.tsx:**

```
import React, {  } from 'react';  
import Page1 from './Page1';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Page2 from './Page2';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  
const App = () => {
  return <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Page1"  component={Page1} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
    </Tab.Navigator>

  </NavigationContainer>
}

export default App
```

**Page1.tsx:**

```
import React, {  } from 'react';
import { Text } from "@react-native-material/core";

const Page1 = () => {
    return <Text>
        I am Page1 ! !!!
    </Text>
}

export default Page1
```

**Page2.tsx:**

```
import React, {  } from 'react';
import { Text } from "@react-native-material/core"

const Page2 = () => {
    return <Text>
        Page 2 is me !!!
    </Text>
}

export default Page2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your NavigationContainer in a View with the styles flex: 1 and overflow: 'hidden.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
};
```